Show if $S$ has a trivial normal bundle, then $S$ is orientable.
I am trying to prove the following exercise from Lee's Smooth Manifolds:

Suppose that $M$ is an orientable Riemannian manifold, and $S\subseteq
 M$ is an immersed or embedded submanifold with or without boundary.
Prove the following statement
Show if $S$ has a trivial normal bundle, then $S$ is orientable.

I use the following theorem in the proof

Proposition 13.21 (The Normal Bundle to a Riemannian Submanifold). $(M, g)$ be a Riemannian n-manifold with or without boundary. For any immersed $k$-dimensional submanifold $S \subseteq M$ with or without boundary, the normal bundle NS is a smooth rank- $(n-k)$ subbundle of $\left. M\right|_S$. For each $p \in S$, there is a smooth frame for NS on a neighborhood of $p$ that is orthonormal with respect to $g$.

Since $NS$ is normal, we have that
$$
N S \cong S \times \mathbb{R}^{n-k}.
$$
Now we will construct an orientation on $S$. Since $M$ is orientable, there is an volume-form $\eta_M$. Fix $p\in M$. By Proposition 13.21 we obtain an orthonormal frame $E_1,\dots,E_{n-k}$ for $NS$. Then we can extend this frame to an orthonormal frame for $M$ with Grahm Schmidt for frames to obtain $\hat E_1,\dots,\hat E_{k},E_{k+1},\dots,E_n$.
Now we define
$${(\eta_S)}_p(v_1,\dots,v_k)= {(\eta_M)}_p\left(v_1,\dots,v_k, \left.E_{k+1}\right|_p,\dots,\left.E_{n}\right|_p\right).$$
My question is how do I ensure that $E_1,\dots,E_k$ is a frame for $S$? I assume this must come from being trivial but I’m not quite sure.
If this were the case, then I could take
$${(\eta_S)}_p(\left.E_1\right|_p,\dots,\left.E_k\right|_p)= {(\eta_M)}_p\left( \left.E_1\right|_p,\dots,\left.E_n\right|_p\right)=1$$
and after joining together with a partition of unity, we obtain a volume form on $S$.

I don’t see why you bother with extending frames. By triviality of the normal bundle, you have $(n-k)$ smooth global sections $\nu_1,\dots,\nu_{n-k}$ of $NS$ over $S$ which at each point form a basis for the normal bundle $NS$.
Let $\eta$ be a volume form on $M$ and define for each $p\in S$ and $v_1,\dots, v_k\in T_pS$,
\begin{align}
(\eta_S)_p(v_1,\dots,v_k):=\eta_p(v_1,\dots, v_k,\nu_1(p),\dots, \nu_{n-k}(p)).
\end{align}
Smoothness of $\eta,\nu_1,\dots,\nu_{n-k}$ imply that for $\eta_S$. So, $\eta_S$ is a smooth $k$-form on $S$. If in fact $\{v_1,\dots, v_k\}$ is a basis for $T_pS$, then since $\{\nu_1(p),\dots,\nu_{n-k}(p)\}$ is a basis for $N_pS$, and since $T_pM=T_pS\oplus N_pS$, it follows $\{v_1,\dots, v_k,\nu_1(p),\dots, \nu_{n-k}(p)\}$ is a basis for $T_pM$, and hence evaluating $\eta$ on this gives a non-zero number (since $\eta$ is nowhere-vanishing). Hence, $\eta_S$ is a volume form on $S$.
So, if you look closely at the proof, it’s not so much the orthogonality which is important, but rather we’re using the fact that  $TS$ has a trivializable complementary subbundle $E$ in $TM|_S$ (but ok of course in geometric situations, one of the first things we look at is the normal bundle).

If originally you start out with $\nu_1,\dots, \nu_{n-k}$ being pointwise orthonormal (which you can always ensure by taking arbitrary linearly independent $\nu_1,\dots,\nu_{n-k}$ and performing the Gram-Schmidt process) and if $\eta$ is a Riemannian volume form (i.e the value on any orthonormal basis is $\pm 1$) then the above $\eta_S$ evaluated on an orthonormal basis for $T_pS$ will also give $1$ (since an orthonormal basis for $T_pS$ and one for $N_pS$ make up one for $T_pM$).

When you say sections of NS do you mean $p\mapsto (p, v_i)$ where$(p,v_i)\in S\times \mathbb{R}^{n-k}$?

@SamKirkiles well technically there is a map $\Phi:NS\to S\times\Bbb{R}^{n-k}$ which is a vector-bundle isomorphism. So, for $i\in {1,\dots, n-k}$, you can take $\nu_i(p)=\Phi^{-1}(p,e_i)$. Setting this aside, I’m using the term section in a completely standard manner. We have $NS$ is a vector bundle over $S$, so a section of this bundle is a map $\nu:S\to NS$ such that for each $p\in S$, $\nu(p)\in N_pS$. I’m just saying that because of triviality (i.e the existence of such a $\Phi$) there exist $\nu_1,\dots, \nu_{n-k}$ which are smooth and pointwise form a basis.

If we didn’t have triviality, could we do this using the local trivialization? Or in this case we need absolutely to have a “global” trivialization of NS?

for this proof, we need the global trivialization of $NS$, otherwise $\eta_S$ is not defined (because if we simply took $\nu$’s from one local trivialization, there’s no saying how they’re related to $\nu$’s from a different local trivialization).

For these sections, would I simply take the basis vectors from R^n-k to be the sections I take? Because for each point in S there is a whole fiber of “normal vectors” I could choose

reread my first comment. ${e_1,\dots,e_{n-k}}$ there is the standard basis of $\Bbb{R}^{n-k}$.

Why do the smoothness of $\eta, \nu_1,\dots, \nu_{n-k}$ imply that $\eta_S$ is smooth?
